# upgrading from jackson 2.6 to jackson 2.7

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to upgrade from Jackson 2.6 to Jackson 2.7 and I'm having a problem when switching to 2.7. It appears that annotations are no longer being processed by Jackson. In particular, I have an @JsonIgnore annotation on a java field which works correctly when run against 2.6, but when run against 2.7 it tries to deserialize the field.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample program to demonstrate the problem? Are you creating an ObjectMapper yourself and using that to serialize the object? If so, how is the ObjectMapper configured?

Comment: it appears this is a conflict with lombok. When I include the lombok annotation @AllArgsConstructor to my class, then I have this problem .

Comment: Is this the same issue you have?  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1122  If so, Jackson 2.7.4 should fix the issue.